# Python: How do I use lists as arguments with a constant co-efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, numpy

I am using Python to plot functions with their arguments as lists (as part of a program to solve differential equations). To begin with, my independent variable is stored in the list **x_array = [xi]**, where **xi** is the initial value. I then use this array in a while loop where the lines **x+=dx** and **x_array.append(x)** allow me to fill this array as required.

The problem I have is when I try to plot an analytical function.

Specifically, this line doesn't work:

```
plt.plot(x_array, 10*np.cos(3*x_array), label = "Analytical Solution")
```

But this line works:

```
plt.plot(x_array, 10*np.cos(x_array), label = "Analytical Solution")
```

The only difference here is the constant scalar co-efficient of 3 inside the cos(3*x_array) argument.

This is the error message I get: *ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension*. The required libraries numpy and matplotlib have been imported, so there's no problem with that.

What is the correct syntax that would allow me to plot the function with the constant co-efficient inside the argument, while still using a list?

Comment: Remember that in Python, you *can* multiply a list by a scalar. And the result is a **longer list**: `x=[1]; y = 3*x; print y` gets [1,1,1].

Comment: How do I write this such that instead of replicating x thrice, I instead have each element of the list multiplied by 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x_array` isn't actually an array, but a python list.

So here's what happens:

```
x_array = [1,2,3]  #as an example
x_array*3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]  # that's what *3 after a list does
```

Instead, if you convert x_array to a numpy array, the multiplication will work as expected.

```
x_array = np.array(x_array) # array([1,2,3])
x_array = x_array *3 # array([3,6,9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the list to a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) using `np.array(x_array)`

Alternatively, use a list comprehension: `[3 * i for i in x_array]`

```
plt.plot(x_array, 10*np.cos(3*np.array(x_array)), label = "Analytical Solution")
```

or

```
plt.plot(x_array, 10*np.cos([3 * i for i in x_array]), label = "Analytical Solution")
```